# Previous view/undo in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to go back to the previous view (not url), or so to speak undo a click in javascript or jquery?

history.go(-1) wouldn't work because the previous view is not literally a url on the address bar. I am using a jquery plugin that create a object (album viewer), and you can navigate between different photos there, the url on the address bar would not change. I set it so that on click of the photo, the page would change to another page.
I want to bring back the user to the previous view, which is the specific photo on the plugin created object.

Comment: I understand that might be related to the object structure; meanwhile I am trying to include the new page inside the same html page that contain the album viewer object... But anyway I mean it as a general question, maybe there are some generic function or method I do not know.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116446/what-is-the-best-back-button-jquery-plugin